# How can I add a container inside a textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried wrapping the textField in a row and adding a container to the row but it throws an error and the rest part of the form doesn't render.
And using the prefix property for textField also doesn't work as the container is shown when the textField is pressed but I want it to be seen even when the textField is not active.

[this is the required UI for the mobile no. field I'm trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxzBH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey[200],
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 50,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 8,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          "+91",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 12,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Mobile No."
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

result:

[image: demo]